# How restreaming shoutcast aac or video live in red5 media server?

Tags: red5, aac, shoutcast

I have red5 running, but now need to create a webapp for the sign of restreaming shoutcast aac, or even receive the signal from the flash media encoder.

Do you have any examples that I can pass? my shoutcast is http://208.53.183.2:8028/ and my red5 is rtmp://208.53.183.2:1936

How can I create an app for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should look into what Andy Shaules has done with these technologies over at http://thebitstream.com/. Specifically his shoutcast transcoder which is here: http://code.google.com/p/castshout/